# \citefield don't work on the urldate field

Tags: biblatex

When I make a reference I would like to have the url of the website and the consultation date in a footnote, and all the information in the bibliography.

I have created a function (`\refbiblio`) for that but I can't get the value of the urldate field, it's not recognized by `\citefield`.

I've checked the `biblatex` package, urldate is a field and there is no command to get it directly (like `\citeurl` for the url).

Here is MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
  \FrenchFootnotes
  \AddThinSpaceBeforeFootnotes
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib} 
@misc{wiki_sdn,
  title={Wikipedia Software-defined networkong},
  url={https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking},
  urldate={2019-02-24}
}
\end{filecontents} 
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}         % Add when use bibtex and babel
\usepackage{xpatch}           % Add when use biblatex and etoolbox
\usepackage[french]{isodate}
\newcommand{\refbiblio}[1]{\footnote{\citeurl{#1}, consulté le \citefield{#1}{urldate} \cite{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Test\refbiblio{wiki_sdn}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And there is a picture of the result I get 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`urldate` is not a normal field, dates internally consist of several fields and must be handled differently, and so it can't be cited with `\citefield`. You could define a `\citeurldate` (like `\citedate`) as

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurldate}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printurldate}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

and use that.

It is, however, much better not to combine several `\cite...` commands into a `\newcommand`. Instead the entire command `\refbiblio` should be declared as a `biblatex` cite command with `\DeclareCiteCommand`. A simple example why `\DeclareCiteCommand` is better than `\newcommand` with several `\cite...`s is that `\DeclareCiteCommand` can handle multiple citations as well as pre- and postnotes properly. If you want to do that with `\newcommand`, additional work is needed. You may also run into issues with citation trackers ('ibid.' etc.) if you combine several `\cite...` commands into a single invocation.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\FrenchFootnotes
\AddThinSpaceBeforeFootnotes

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{isodate}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fnurlcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
@misc{wiki_sdn,
  title   = {Wikipedia Software-defined networking},
  url     = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking},
  urldate = {2019-02-24},
}
\end{filecontents} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test\fnurlcite{wiki_sdn}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: url: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_networking, visité le 24/02/2019 [1].]