# How to access urldate in text

Tags: biblatex

I have to print the date when I visited a website in the main text of my thesis.
Can I automatically do this with `biblatex`?

Comment: Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477452/35864

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no predefined command to do that, but it is simple to define a command `\citeurldate` analogous to `\citedate` (see [`biblatex.def`, ll. 2183-2189](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2183-L2189)). Note the redefinition of the `urldate` format (`\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{####1}`) in the precode argument of `\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurldate}` to avoid the additional "visited on" string and parentheses (the `#` character had to be doubled twice because this is a nested macro definition, see [What is the meaning of double pound symbol (number sign, hash character) ##1 in an argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/35864)).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurldate}
  {\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{####1}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printurldate}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{markey} from \citeurldate{markey}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Markey 2005 from 01/10/2006]

Comment: +1: Good as always, could you point out "Note the redefinition of the urldate format in the precode argument" as a comment in the code?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I usually try to avoid excessive code comments and I think that in this case it is quite clear where the redefinition happens, so I'd rather not add a comment. Is there any specific reason why you ask about that? Maybe I can make the text of the answer more clear so the comment isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! One additional question:
Can one redefine the \parentice command just for @online sources, that it adds the urldate in a postnote?

Comment: @mathse In general yes, but how will depend on the style you use. Please open a new question and post a short example document (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows which style you use.

Comment: @moewe thanks, I posted a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521238/how-to-add-urldate-to-first-citation-in-online-references
Thanks again for the answer here!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not see where/what the `precode` is. But maybe I should consult the `biblatex` manual (RTFM) :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I see, I tried to add a few more pointers to the text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for considering my comment :). I upvote anyway :).